# PHP Looping based on date

Tags: php, loops

ok so i have this array of about 151 elements and there is a date field as one of the elements. The array is a two week range. I want to count how many elements are in the first week and how any are in the second week. Here is my example array.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4d50
        [date] => 07-10-2010
        [telephone] => something
        [Sno] => 1
     )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4g50
        [date] => 07-03-2010
        [telephone] => something
        [Sno] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 4s50
        [date] => 06-29-2010
        [telephone] => something
        [Sno] => 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getweek($a){
   //altered code., m-d-Y is no a format strtotime likes):
   return  DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y',$a['date'])->format('W');
}
var_dump(array_count_values(array_map('getweek',$inputarray)));
```

Comment: no i need each weeks count so i need the week from 07-03-10 to 07-10-10 and the previous weeks count also

Comment: Euhm, that's what it does? Go ahead & test (keep in mind the ISO-8601 week starts on monday)

Comment: Also: you example is not a 2-week range b.t.w. Or am I understanding the 'range' you talk about incorrectly?

Comment: my range is from 7-10-10 to 6-27-10
so it is 2 weeks and the previous example didnt work...still testing

Comment: @Wrikken,you need to reformat OP's time to make your solution work.